# Running a single line/snippet in Python 3 and returning result to Python 2

Tags: python

What is the best way to execute a single-line of Python 3 and return the result to a Python 2 program. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2 
# Not valid code
pwsd = exec("python3 -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt(\"<password_str>\",salt=crypt.METHOD_SHA512))'")
```

Comment: `exec` is for executing a string of python code https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec but here you are passing it something like a shell script to run the python3 intepreter. Try running that with https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html instead

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679722/exec-python2-script-from-python3 can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Thanks Anentropic.

```
subprocess.check_output(['python3', '-c', 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("<password_str",salt=crypt.METHOD_SHA512))'])
```